# :new and :old values dynamically in oracle Trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c, database-trigger

I have to track the data changes in a single audit table test_audit which can be used in other triggers to track the changes. I have tried this code but stuck in populating old and new values .
Any help on this is much appreciated.

```
create table test (ID NUMBER , ENAME VARCHAR2(10) , LOCATION VARCHAR2(10));

 create or replace trigger my_trigger
    after update on TEST
    for each row
    declare
       ACTION VARCHAR2(10);
     begin
    
    IF DELETING THEN
          ACTION := 'DELETE';
        ELSIF UPDATING THEN
          ACTION := 'UPDATE';
        END IF;
                 
       for i in (select column_name,table_name from all_tab_columns
                 where table_name = 'TEST'
                 )
       loop
         if updating(i.column_name) then
          INSERT
          INTO TEST_AUDIT
            (
                TABLE_NAME,
                COLUMN_NAME,
                OLD_VALUE,
                NEW_VALUE,
                ACTION,
                UPDATED_BY,
                UPDATED_DT
                        )
            VALUES
            (   
                i.table_name,
                i.column_name,
             --   :old.column_name,--- how to get old and new values?
              --  :new.column_name,---
                ACTION,         
               USER,
               SYSDATE
            );
       end if;
       end loop;
       
    end;
```

Comment: Read this answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62858490/convert-the-new-row-to-xml-inside-a-oracle-trigger/62861136?noredirect=1#comment111166753_62861136 And this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62977588/xmltype-in-oracle-not-generating-tags-for-columns-with-null-values/62979379?noredirect=1#comment111371354_62979379

Comment: From what I can tell this is a question about using dynamic PL/SQL to obtain the value  of :old and :new field values, and I don't think you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

The variables called :new and :old (unless you decide to rename them in the declaration of the trigger) are variables of the rowtype of the table you place the trigger on. So you use :new.<column_name> and :old.<column_name>.

Comment: That is exactly what they're saying. But why are you growing your own auditing? It is a topic way way more complex and complicated than simply writing old and new values to a table  That is why you let the DBMS do it for you, See [Traditional Auditing](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_4007.htm#SQLRF01107) and/or [Unified Auditing](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/auditing-enhancements-12cr1) or just google "Oracle Auditing"

Comment: Yes. You have to hardcode the column name there because PL/SQL is a compiled language. You can not do that dynamically. To be more precise: You can use dynamic. sql but the performance hit is gigantic so generally speaking you do not want that.

Comment: If you do want to do things "cynically" your best option is to write a PL/SQL package that will look at meta data dictionary to generate the sources of the trigger automatically.